# The following C++ with OpenCV code is not getting compiled

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<cv.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1]);
   cvSaveImage( argv[2] , img);
   cvReleaseImage( &img );
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error: "unreferenced arguement cvloadimage". I'm new to this, trying to learn by myself. Any help will be most appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Since you're new to this, here is the first advice: do not ever use old C-style OpenCV (IplImage, cvLoadImage, etc.), use only new C++-style OpenCV (cv::Mat, cv::imread, etc.).

Comment: Do you know of a good book I could use? Or some tutorials on the Internet? I basically need to develop a Hand Gesture Recognition Software..

Comment: Standard tutorials look nice: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: Been there, but it is all about Mat. The sad bit is, I am sitting with a Prof's code which needs to be improved(more gestures to be recognized..) and it uses IplImage :/

Comment: bad excuse. if you don't change it, the next student after you will suffer even harder. 3.0 will it make *significantly* more difficult to use the c-api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use the C interface and code with C++. Like @Mikhal said you should stay away from `IplImage` and stick to `Mat`. Many of the methods are similarly named and if you have any questions you can always do a quick Google search or look on OpenCV's API reference. I was actually brutally surprised by this fact too just a few weeks ago, but I now use my outdated C OpenCV textbook as a reference for methodology and not exact code/programs.